# Export xml use/import images from theme directory

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, media, export, xml

Is it possible to create demo.xml for a theme that when imported into fresh theme installation will use/import images from theme directory folder (e.g. theme/images/demo) rather than import media from previous wordpress installation? If possible, how it can be achieved?

Comment: Interesting question, however my first guess would be that it's complicated to achieve with XML import alone since it would have no knowledge _where_ theme files are.